# How do I set a type for a list of html elements?

Tags: typescript

I'm generating a list of options for a `<select>` element and push `<option>` elements into that array. Right now the type of the array is `any[]`. But how to set a correct type for such an array?

```
let items: any[] = [];
     
for (let i = 0; i <= 30; i++) {             
  items.push(<option key={i} value={i}>{i}</option>);   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of a React element is `JSX.Element`:

```typescript
let items: JSX.Element[] = [];
//         ^^^^^^^^^^^
     
for (let i = 0; i <= 30; i++) {             
    items.push(<option key={i} value={i}>{i}</option>);
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=3&ssc=1&pln=8&pc=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocgGyXmBiRAGcAuOAKQGUANAOgFEaIJADsYAbQC6cALxwpFAPSK4qtWoB6W7To3l1ccpmhwAFDTqy4ABlJxgcADxyAzLfsBqDwEo4AbwNA1X01ekYmXjAAVyYAC1NHCDAYYAgROABrJABPGT9gAF84ADcUKiikPMKAPnyCx0UklLTq7woCoA)

Beware that these are **not** "`option` elements" (that is, they aren't [`HTMLOptionElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement) instances). They're `JSX.Element` instances that, when rendered via React, will create `HTMLOptionElement` instances in the document.

Comment: Would `React.ReactNode[]` be the more preferred type instead?

Comment: @Harkunwar - It depends on what you're using the array for. In this case, it only ever contains `JSX.Element` instances, so there's really no need for the broader `React.ReactNode` type. But yes, that would also work.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder could you please tell where to read more about all that types?

Comment: @newbie222 - I haven't seen this well-documented anywhere. What I've learned about React types has been by looking at other project source code and kicking around the type definitions at https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/react, sadly.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder okay, thanks. But where do other programmers get that information from?? :D

Comment: @newbie222 - With a decent IDE, you can explore types by doing something like `const opt = <option/>;` and then hovering your mouse cursor over the top of `opt` to see its type. In VSCode you can right click `opt` and choose **Go to Type Definition** to go to where VSCode is getting type information for that identifier from (to see the definition of that type). I use that to discover types. More generally, there are two ways to get TypeScript type definitions for packages: 1. The package itself provides the types, or 2. Some third party provides the types. Most of #2 is via...

Comment: ...the massive project called DefinitelyTyped (https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped, https://www.typescriptlang.org/dt/) that provides type definitions for packages that don't provide it themselves (or that choose to distribute them via that project). (There's a great search page for it [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/dt/search?search=).) So basically you either pick that up from other developers or the documentation of projects, discover it via your IDE, or learn it as part of learning TypeScript (via a book or course).